# Fetching input box value on submit button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am working on a game using `ImpactJS` engine and I have created a basic form for my game which contains input box and a submit button. I am able to retrieve values from the input box but what I want is that when the player clicks on submit whatever value is there in the input box gets fetched and I should be able to get that value on Submit click. If the value is null I should get an alert saying "no value or whatever". I want to use this final value and assign it to a variable that I can use in my JavaScript files inside the Impact engine to keep a track of the input from within the game. I am new to HTML, CSS in general so I have no clue how to achieve this.

Below is my HTML/CSS code that has an input box and a submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Impact Game</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 12pt;
        }
        #problemform {
            display: none;
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        #probleminput {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            top: 450px;
            left: 240px;
            height: 50px;
            width: 350px;
        }
        #problemsubmit {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            top: 530px;
            left: 623px;
            height: 40px;
            width: 100px;
            padding: 5px 10px 8px 2px;
        }
        #prob_submit_msg {
            width: 30%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #canvaswrapper {
            position: relative;
            height: 768px;
            width: 1024px;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 80px;
            vertical-align: middle;

        }
        #canvas {

            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: auto;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/impact/impact.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/game/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="canvaswrapper">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
    <div id="problemform" class="form-inline">
        <input id="probleminput" class="form-inline" type="text" style="display: inline;"></input>
        <button id="problemsubmit" class="btn" style="display: inline-block;">Submit</button>
    </div>
        <div id ="prob_submit_mssg" style="display: block;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my block of code in `ImpactJS` in a different JS file to display the input box and submit button using Jquery

```
ProblemDisplay:function() {
            this.setQuestion('This is a title','this is where the body will go and it will be super long and impossible to read or understand.', 'This is a hint');
            this.isActive = true;
            var form = $("#problemform");
            var inputBox = $("#probleminput");
            var submitButton = $("#problemsubmit");
            form.show();
            inputBox.show();
            submitButton.show();
        },
```

This is what I have working for now. But now I want the string passed in the input box to be stored in a different variable when clicking the submit button. How to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: So, you just need to have an event for submit button and when the submit button event firred get the value from input? That's it?

Comment: Yea basically its much more complicated though. Its like a question answer interface that we have built. So whenever the player enters an answer in the text field and presses submit, I have to store that answer in some variable. I should be able to use that variable in my js file to check if the answer matches the stored answer in our database (mongodb). This is the design. I don't know if I am on the right track to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try With this.. :

html:

```
<input id="probleminput" class="form-inline" type="text" style="display: inline;">   </input>
<button id="problemsubmit" class="btn" style="display: inline-block;">Submit</button>

<a id='testop' ></a>
```

Js:

```
var form = $("#problemform");
var inputBox = $("#probleminput");
var submitButton = $("#problemsubmit");
submitButton.click(function(){
var getval = ($("#probleminput").val()?$("#probleminput").val():alert('please fill the   text field'))
$('#testop').text(getval);  
});
```

[Complete DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/4stUe/)

Comment: Hi, is there any way to check if the submit button was clicked like a flag value (true,false)? I tried declaring a global boolean variable in my script and set it to true inside the click function but it does not set itself to true. Is there any way to know if the user clicked on submit button?

Comment: set the bool var outside of click function then it will works..
`var bool=true;$('sub').click(function(){if(bool){/*something*/ bool=false} })` @JimZilla

Answer (score 3):

**Create an event listener for a click on the submit button.**

*In jQuery:*

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function() {

});
```

*In vanilla js*

```
document.getElementById('submit-button').addEventListener('click', function() {

});
```

**Then get the value from the input box:**

*In jQuery:*

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function() {
    var value = $('input').val(); 
    // Do what you want with the value
});
```

*In vanilla js*

```
document.getElementById('submit-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
    // Do what you want with the value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the value of the input field when someone clicks on the button, then this solution may work for you:

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gV5Pt/)**

JS:

```
$('#problemsubmit').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formInput = $('#probleminput').val();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got everything except what does this line of code do? $('#prob_submit_mssg').html(formInput);

Comment: @user3311433 sorry, I was using that line for testing purposes. If you check out the demo you'll see it updates the div with whatever is entered in the input box. I'll edit my answer to remove it.

Comment: okay thanks but now how do I fetch the formInput value as it is a local variable inside the event function. I want to be able to use that value in other functions to compare it with the another variable which is stored in the database

Comment: define `formInput` on a higher scope. I don't know how your code is set up, but somewhere in the containing function (like the one you listed in your question), or global scope will do.

Comment: Yea I did that first thing but I don't know ImpactJS engine behaves weird at times. I fixed it though. Thank you so much!